# Retrieving keyboard interrupt result in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, keyboard, interrupt-handling, pagedown

I have CListCtrl and I'm trying to handle some keyboard buttons such as
page-up / page-down etc. I'm using OnLvnKeydown handler.
My problem is retrieving the item's index AFTER the keyboard interrupt. For instance, if item 1 is marked and I press page-down I want to show the details of the new item that is now marked, yet all functions that are offered - GetFirstSelectedItemPosition, GetSelectionMark, etc - returns the item selected when the interrupt occurred, meaning item 1.
Does anyone know how to handle this issue? How can I retrieve the index of the new marked item after the interrupt has finished?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your message map add

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGING, YOUR_LIST_CONTROL_ID, &CYourDialog::OnItemchanging)
```

then implement the OnItemchanging

```cpp
void CYourDialog::OnItemchanging(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{

    // LVN_ITEMCHANGING notification handler
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    // is the user selecting an item?
    if ((pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMLV->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED))
    {       
        // do what you want with your selected item pNMLV
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```